# How to plot a ROC curve for a SVM model in R

Tags: r, svm, roc

I have trained and tested a model using the following code

```
library(e1071)
library(readxl)
library(caret)

class1.svm.model <- svm(Class ~ ., data = class1.trainset,cost=20, cross=10,type="C-classification",kernel="radial",na.action=na.omit)
class1.svm.pred <- predict(class1.svm.model, class1.testset)
finalmatrix<-data.matrix(class1.svm.pred, rownames.force = F)

test<-table(pred = class1.svm.pred, true = class1.testset[,c(15768)])

confusionMatrix(test)
```

But unable to plot a ROC curve for the model. please help me with the correct syntax to plot a ROC curve to see the performance of my test data.

Comment: Over what parameter do you want to plot the ROC?

Comment: Based on performance of the model, based on  "tpr", "fpr"

Comment: You create the ROC plot for multiple models, especially if they are parametrized by some continuous measure. It looks like you have obtained just one model, thus you have one tupel of "tpr" and "fpr".

Comment: What if i try ranging cost and gamma values and try to plot a ROC curve with that?

Answer (score 1):

Ploting ROC curve for SVM with class:

```
roc_svm_test <- roc(response = class1.trainset$Class, predictor =as.numeric(class1.svm.pred))
plot(roc_svm_test, add = TRUE,col = "red", print.auc=TRUE, print.auc.x = 0.5, print.auc.y = 0.3)
legend(0.3, 0.2, legend = c("test-svm"), lty = c(1), col = c("blue"))
```